# Jenkins reading a file(zip) from build paramameter

Tags: jenkins

[new to jenkins]I am trying to read a file from input(parameterised build). and use that for wget and downloading onto a server/slave.

example: when we click on Build with parameter, it should ask for the zip file location hosted on a server file format (http://xxx/xxx/xxx/xx.zip) and in the build step i need some thing like this : ssh xxxxx[host]: 'cd /temp/abc;wget file from parameter'

How to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic question.

Create a job with a String parameter:

[image]

Next, use add an "Execute shell" build step like that:

[image]

If you want to download the file on a specific machine, just launch a Jenkins slave agent on this machine and execute the job on this slave (instead of running the job on the master server).

Launch your build with the file URL:

[image]

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test wget with parameter/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson3280603023156720832.sh
--2015-11-25 09:47:32--  http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/p/p7zip/p7zip_9.20.1~dfsg.1.orig.tar.gz
Resolving http.debian.net... 5.153.231.35, 128.31.0.66, 176.9.184.93, ...
Connecting to http.debian.net|5.153.231.35|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://debian.univ-lorraine.fr/debian/pool/main/p/p7zip/p7zip_9.20.1~dfsg.1.orig.tar.gz [following]
--2015-11-25 09:47:32--  http://debian.univ-lorraine.fr/debian/pool/main/p/p7zip/p7zip_9.20.1~dfsg.1.orig.tar.gz
Resolving debian.univ-lorraine.fr... 193.54.21.4
Connecting to debian.univ-lorraine.fr|193.54.21.4|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4215388 (4.0M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: “/tmp/test.zip”

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 1.28M 3s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2% 2.46M 2s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  3% 2.63M 2s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 10.7M 2s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  6% 2.71M 2s
```